# How to find physical location of an application by name?

Tags: terminal, finder

I can open Terminal and execute `open -a "iPhone Simulator"` and as long as the application is installed, it will launch. Is there a similar command that will return the path to the application instead of launching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type this:

> find /Applications -name "Safari"

you will find the Safari.app for example. I do not have iPhone Simulator, thus I cannot test that one.

If you type

> mdfind "Safari"

you will find all records containing Safari (or iPhone Simulator).

**Note:** safari is not the best option to search for as it is a native program

Comment: `find` isn't going to be very useful since you have to put the path in front of the application so you'd already know what @michael-teper is asking for.

Comment: He asked for an Application which is installed. Since default location is /Applications, that isn't very weird is it?
Besides, if /Applications does not work, you can use / instead. Resulting in some access denied errors and results.

Comment: Per @Robuust, `find /Applications -name "iPhone Simulator"` does work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mdfind 'kMDItemContentType=com.apple.application-bundle&&kMDItemFSName=MacVim.app'
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-71/MacVim.app
$ osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to app "MacVim")'
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-71/MacVim.app/
$ lsregister -dump|grep '^\tpath: .*/MacVim\.app$'
    path:          /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-71/MacVim.app
```

Or if the application is running:

```
$ lsappinfo info -app MacVim -only kLSBundlePathKey
"LSBundlePath"="/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-71/MacVim.app"
```